# Did Lingodbhava incident take place twice in this Kalpa?

Tags: shiva, temple, shiva-lingam

In Thirukandiyur near Thanjavur district, there is a temple for Brahma dev by the name Brahma Sira Kandeeswarar temple. It is believed that lingodbhava incident of where Shiva appearing in linga form to kill Ahankara of Brahma took place. This was the place where Lord Shiva first appeared as Kala Bhairava.

It is during this period where Kala Bhairava seemed to have nullified his Brahmahatya dosha in Kashi.

So now my question is, did this Shiva linga incident took place twice in this Kalpa? Do we have reference for it?

Comment: It happened outside cosmic egg. It would be too easy for Brahma dev to find top and bottom of fire pillar if it happened inside cosmic egg or on earth. It happened before creation, after all, Brahma dev would not be aware about who Lord Shiva is before commencing creation and at the start of kalpa and not after everything had already been created.

Comment: From what I heard in my visits to sacred places, two places in south India is where Lingodbhava took place and Bhairava form of Shiva came from it. So, I am seeking for proper reference on how this incident happened. Subject of infinity seems so vast and taking me lot of time to realize it!

Comment: If you look at famous saying " if you end your life in Kashi, you'll get Mukti" - In Kashi, the story behind Bhairava is it is the place where Bhairava got freed from Brahamahati Dosha for taking out Brahma's head. Then something is missing?

Comment: Didn't get the Q...how you reach the conclusion that it might have happened twice..? let's say as per you it happened in Thirukandiyur..And as per scriptures Bhairava wondered here and there to come out from the Bhrahmhatya and finally nullified it in Kashi...

Comment: The question is clear @YDS. Shiva linga incident had happened at the start of Mahakalpa outside of Cosmic egg as per our Puranas. But last year my visit to that temple in Thanjavur districts, heard from them that Shiva appeared as Bhairava first there to kill Brahma dev ahankara. So I raised this question on any references that did this happen twice?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS outside of cosmic egg, which Purana says so...? in fact Puranas say that Vishnu taking the form of boar went in Patal Loka to figure out it's base and Brahma taking a form of swan went upward..? Is Patala Loka outside of cosmic egg...? u can say that root of piller of fire was beyond cosmic egg but still the war bw Brahma & Vishnu happened inside cosmic egg and then Bhairva manifestation too..that's what i think...pls correct me if i m wrong..

Comment: What is the relation between Shivalingodbhavam and Brahma's temple at Tirukkandiyur?? Looks like you are mixing two different stories. Temple history doesn't mention lingodhbhavam.

Comment: The other temple you're thinking of is the Arunachaleshwarar temple in Thiruvannamalai, right?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - in that district of temple,  I heard that's where Shiva appeared as first Bhairava to kill Brahma ahankara as he lied that he found top of linga. That's why I was confused and asked on references for Shiva linga incident

Comment: That is not right. This temple is related with Brahma and Shatarupa story. KalaBhairava plucks off the head of Brahma. Even in the story of  Lingodbhava in the Shiva Purana, Shiva curses flower, cow and Brahma but does not pluck his head. These are two different stories. Lingodbhava doesn't have Kala Bhairava. http://www.findmytemple.com/en/sivan-temple/t14-brahmasira-kandeeswarar,-thirukandiyur

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - can you post it with reference on it? Since I do not know the difference between the two properly, i have asked this question!